# Result binding in mysqli

Tags: mysqli

In the following example, can any folks show me how to code the binding part as I select all fields from the table

```
$stmt = $mysqli_conn->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM books")) {
    $stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result( **WHAT DO I PUT HERE** );

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bind_result`, you put in the variables where you want to fetch the data into, instead of using an array returned otherwise.

```
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4);
while($stmt->fetch_assoc())
    echo "$col1 $col2 $col3 $col4";
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to bind the result

```
while($resultArray = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "$resultArray[columnName1] $resultArray[columnName2] ...";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Question: 1. if I use SELECT *, then it will return all columns in the table in the sequence of the table structure? 2. In you sample, does it mean I can select particular columns?

Comment: Let me close this once and re-post a more direct question.